# Setting a dropbox value from the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an add form that allows me to add the specific field into the database and one of my options is a dropdown menu so that I can set the form type:

I now in the process of creating the edit page and I have called the other values as `$field->name` etc but how would I call `$field->type` to set the specific value for the dropdown menu?

My Add view is:

```
<label for="edit_fields_type">Type: </label>
<select name="edit_fields_type" id="edit_fields_type">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="input" <?php echo set_select('edit_fields_type','input', ( !empty($fieldType) && $fieldType == "input" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Input</option>
    <option value="textarea" <?php echo set_select('edit_fields_type','textarea', ( !empty($fieldType) && $fieldType == "textarea" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Text Area</option>
    <option value="radiobutton" <?php echo set_select('edit_fields_type','radiobutton', ( !empty($fieldType) && $fieldType == "radiobutton" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Radio Button</option>
    <option value="checkbox" <?php echo set_select('edit_fields_type','checkbox', ( !empty($data) && $data == "checkbox" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Check Box</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What does set_select do?

Comment: I think you need some further clarification,its difficult to know exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @TobyAllen  I would like to set the dropdown menu by the value that is given in the db = if input is set the menu will show input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you want from the form helper is the third parameter of form_dropdown() which allows you to specify the selected item. Possibly:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$options = array('input' => 'Input','textarea' => 'Text Area','radiobutton' => 'Radio Button','checkbox' => 'Checkbox',);
echo form_dropdown('edit_fields_type', $options, $field->type);
```

Where $field->type is wherever you have the selected value in your model.

Comment: Yes I have an option in the DB that is set at input textarea etc and I want this to be the selected property when I load the page.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$options = array(
                  'input'  => 'Input',
                  'textarea'    => 'Text Area',
                  'radiobutton'   => 'Radio Button',
                  'checkbox' => 'Checkbox',
                );

echo form_dropdown('edit_fields_type', $options, set_select('edit_fields_type', $fieldType));
```

Comment: No that just sets the first one in the array.  The selected value should be what ever is set into $field->type as the first option but also show the other options incase the user would like to change it

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="input" <?php echo (set_value('edit_fields_type', $fieldType) == "input") ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Input</option>
```